# Guidance on Subquery at Expression at MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Have a requirement as below,

1. Table1 having Employee ids and Managers id
2. Query1 having only distinct manager ids

Requirement: Create a query with Employee id and an expression as Whether that employee is a manager or not

```
SELECT [Table1].Empld,        
       IIf(((Select count(*) from [Query1] where [Query1].[Manager]=[Table1].[Empld]) >  0),"Yes","No") AS IsManager
FROM [Table1]
```

But this query is not working :(. Please advise how we can achieve this

**Updating additional comments:**

Table1:

| Empld | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |

Query1:
SELECT DISTINCT [Table1].Manager
FROM [Table1];

Result of Query1:

| Manager |
| --- |
| 9 |
| 1 |
| 2 |

**New Query - Query2 (Final Result):**

Query2:

SELECT [Table1].Empld,
IIf(((Select count(*) from [Query1] where [Query1].[Manager]=[Table1].[Empld]) >  0),"Yes","No") AS IsManager
FROM [Table1]

**Expected Result with expression:**

| Empld | IsManager |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | Yes |
| 3 | No |
| 4 | No |
| 5 | No |

But when running query2, it is getting as below

| Empld | IsManager |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | Yes |
| 3 | Yes |
| 4 | Yes |
| 5 | Yes |

As we see here, 3, 4 & 5 are not managers but the query in expression is returning as "Yes".

As always, Thanks a lot for guidance
Nathan
:)

Comment: Is `Empld` typed correctly? It looks like EMPLD. Should be EMPID??

Comment: Thanks Wazz, yes it was correct. Just did one more check with Access DB.

Comment: Odd to use lower case "l" instead of "i" in an identifier field name. Still did not specify what "not working" means.

Comment: Should also provide sample data as text table and SQL of Query1. Solution can probably utilize table self-join.

Comment: Hi HansUp - thanks - apologize missed your comment. Added additional details above. Thanks!!
Hi June7, updated query as well on above. Checking on self-join. Thanks!!

Comment: When I removed the brackets around empId the code worked.  I haven't been able to figure out why as the brackets shouldn't affect the code.  I can't post as an answer without a why but here is the resulting sql: SELECT EmpId, IIf(((Select count(*) from [Query1] where [Query1].[Manager]=EmpId)>0),"Yes","No") AS IsManager
FROM Table1;  (also my code uses a capital i in EmpId not a lowercase L)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mazoula :) - After removing brackets - it worked :).